# Leaflet: blank page after refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, leaflet

I am using leaflet.js in a Rails 4 application.
I have a page called fields, where I show a map. The page displays well, but when I refresh it, the rendered result is a blank page.

Here is my javascript code:

```
# app/assets/javascript/fields.js.coffee
$(document).ready ->
  map = L.map('map')

  L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/my-API-KEY/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
      maxZoom: 18
  }).addTo(map)

  bounds = new L.LatLngBounds
  for field in $(".field_in_map")
    $field = $(field)
    latlng = [$field.data("latitude"), $field.data("longitude")]
    bounds.extend(latlng)
    desc = $field.data("description")
    addr = $field.data("address")
    marker = L.marker(latlng).addTo(map)
    marker.bindPopup("<a href=#{addr} data-no-turbolink><b>#{desc}</b></a><br>")

  map.fitBounds(bounds)
  if $(".field_in_map").length==1 && $(".field_in_map").data("zoom")
    map.setZoom($(".field_in_map").data("zoom"))
```

My index page:

```
# app/views/fields/index.html.erb
…
    <% @fields.each do |field| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, class: "field_in_map", data: { latitude: field.latitude, longitude: field.longitude, description: print_field(field), address: field_path(field) } do %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <div id="map" class="map_with_all_fields"></div>
…
```

My gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
…
gem 'leaflet-rails'
…
```

In my configurations, I have **config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false** and **config.serve_static_assets = true**.

Before launching the server, I generate the assets:

```
$> rake assets:precompile
```

Once the server is up, I visit the index page for fields and everything is ok. But once I press CMD+R (refresh), I have a blank page.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: No, no error is displayed in the console. I've tried to see the source from my browser (safari), but the sub-menu for displaying the source is disabled because I guess the page is blank.
However, I've checked on another computer, and I don't have this issue. This may come from the browser settings.